# How to generate email suggestions in Java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to generate a list of email suggestions using the combination of user's first, middle, and last name in java.

As an example,

```
User full name: "First Middle Last"
then the list of suggestions can be:
"first.last@gmail.com"
"last.first@gmail.com"
"first.m.last@gmail.com"
.
.
"first.last1@gmail.com"
"last.first1@gmail.com"
"first.last2@gmail.com"
"last.first2@gmail.com"
```

One way is to use if conditions and manually generate them using string concatenation and substring, but is there any better way?

This is what I have done(But I am manually creating the aliases):

```
    String displayName = user.getFullName();
    String[] wordsInName = displayName.split("[ -]");
    if(wordsInName.length==1) {
        String firstName = wordsInName[0];
        emailAliases.add(firstName+domain);
        emailAliases.add(firstName+1+domain);
        emailAliases.add(firstName+2+domain);
        emailAliases.add(firstName+3+domain);
        emailAliases.add(firstName+4+domain);
    }

    if(wordsInName.length==2) {
        String firstName = wordsInName[0];
        String lastName = wordsInName[1];
        String username1 = firstName+"." + lastName;
        String username2 = lastName + "." + firstName;
        emailAliases.add(username1+domain);
        emailAliases.add(username2+domain);
        emailAliases.add(username2+1+domain);
        emailAliases.add(username1+1+domain);
    }

    if(wordsInName.length==3) {
        String firstName = wordsInName[0];
        String lastName = wordsInName[2];
        String middleName = wordsInName[1];
        String username1 = firstName+"." + lastName;
        String username2 = lastName + "." + firstName;
        emailAliases.add(username1+domain);
        emailAliases.add(username2+domain);
        emailAliases.add(username2+middleName.charAt(0)+domain);
        emailAliases.add(username1+middleName.charAt(0)+domain);
    }
```

Comment: You could also consider String.format.

Comment: What you are probably looking for is Array permutation https://www.baeldung.com/java-array-permutations